# Show row validation message in blade file for Laravel Excel data - maatwebsite-excel

Tags: php, excel, laravel, validation, maatwebsite-excel

**What I'm trying to acheive?**

- Validate the records available in the `csv file` that I have uploaded using `maatwebsite/excel`.
- Set custom validation rules:

  **i.e.**

```
    contact_number to be integer and 13 digits
    email to be strictly email etc
```

- If all the csv file data is valid then upload in database and show
  message.
- If certain feild of the table is missing or not according to custom validation rules set above  then show those data rows of the csv file in the blade and give user the option to update the feild and upload that data to DB.

**What I'm doing?**

Using Laravel Excel, I'm importing the data. I am not quite sure how the back end works.

```
public function import(Request $request)
    {
        Excel::import(new CustomersImport, $request->file);
        return back()->with('success', 'User Imported Successfully.');
    }
```

What [Row Validation](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/validation.html) is showing is that they set the rules inside rules() function inside the import class and create model with table feilds. Tbh I really don't know how csv data is being transferred here. Data is also not uploading in database.
Whwn I enter `dd($row)` inside the `model(array $row)` it shows the recod of only first row of the table.

```
class CustomersImport implements ToModel, WithHeadingRow
{
    use Importable;
    public function rules(): array
    {
        return [
           'name' => 'required|string',
           'email' => 'required|string',
        ];
    }

    public function model(array $row)
    {
        return new Customer([
            "name" => $row['name'],
            "email" => $row['email'],
            "contact" => $row['contact'],
            "address" => $row['address'],
            "nutritionplan_id" => $row['nutritionplan_id'],
            "company_id" => $row['company_id'],
        ]);
    }
}
```

`blade` file. I actuality, I want I want to show table with records that are not validated if it have errors. But for now I'm just trying to show error.

```
 @if (count($errors) > 0)
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-1">
            <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                <h4><i class="icon fa fa-ban"></i> Error!</h4>
                @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
                {{ $error }} <br>
                @endforeach
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    @endif

    @if (Session::has('success'))
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-1">
            <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                <h5>{!! Session::get('success') !!}</h5>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    @endif
```